# MariaDB 10.3 - Upgrade to 10.3 failed

Tags: mysql, repository, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I download and upgrade the repository but when I tried to install MariaDB 10.3 the installation was failed. Here is the log (in spanish):

```
davidl@DM-DAVIDL:~$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-clientLeyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 mariadb-client : Depende: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.7+maria~bionic) pero no va a instalarse
 mariadb-server : Depende: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.7+maria~bionic) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

How can I upgrade MariaDB to 10.3?

Comment: 10.3.what?  That is, what is the 3rd part of the version number -- both before and after the upgrade.

Comment: The last stable version 10.3.7.